# Call layout Android from another class

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have main Activity:

```
public class Clip15 extends Activity{}
```

I want call tableLayout from class GenerateView in main class Clip15:

```
public class GenerateView {
      public void generateInputView(String [] inputHeaderTvs, String [] inputTvs, Context context, LinearLayout inputLinearLayout){

                final TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);
                final TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rowParams.bottomMargin = 0;

                final TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
                tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
                inputLinearLayout.addView(tableLayout);

                TableRow rowOutputHeader = new TableRow(context);
                rowOutputHeader.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
                TextView outputHeader = new TextView(context);
                outputHeader.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                outputHeader.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.outputHeaderTv);
                outputHeader.setText("Dane wejściowe");
                rowOutputHeader.addView(outputHeader);
                tableLayout.addView(rowOutputHeader);
    }}
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of your function to:

```
public static void generateInputView(String [] inputHeaderTvs, String [] inputTvs, Context context, LinearLayout inputLinearLayout) {
    //rest of the code
}
```

and call in your Clip class with the correct params:

```
GenerateView.generateInputView(inputHeaders, inputTvs, context, inputLayout);
```

inputHeaders, inputTvs, context and inputLayout are your arguments that you pass to the function above. They should be initialized already.

Comment: There should be Context and LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes, see an update. Then in your Clip15 class, call the static function as shown with the arguments you want to pass.

Comment: Ok, it's work, I have one question, in class GenerateView i want change line:outputHeader.setText("Dane jhjhwejściowe"), to:outputHeader.setText(getString(getResources().getIdentifier(value , "string", getPackageName()))), I have error :Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.

Comment: It's a new issue so please post another question regarding this, and remember to include logcat in your question. Tip: try context you've passed, so: context.getString(context.getResources().getIdentifier...